# Pre-existing test framework for message brokers?

Tags: integration-testing, messaging, messagebroker

I'm interested in writing a message broker (for fun / learning experience). So I'm wondering, are there any test frameworks for message brokers where I can just plug in a URL and port and it'll run some tests? I'm willing to make my broker use whatever interface the test needs (like STOMP or AMQP). I know it's unlikely, but since there's a bunch of these and they all use a small number of interfaces, it seems possible. I won't be writing this in Java, so something that requires a `vm://` URL won't work.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you'll find a framework for this, but you may want to look at the tests contained in spring-integration and it's submodules (amqp, stomp, etc.).
not sure what you mean by jvm:// URL

Comment: A bunch of message brokers are written in Java and communicate through the local JVM. For example, I wouldn't be surprised if ActiveMQ's unit tests assumed a local JVM broker.

Comment: true, in that case you have to use a URL like vm://localhost. I am not aware of the jvm: URL though.

Comment: you are after a test framework though and i believe you may find solutions in the spring-amqp /spring-integration or activemq test sources. I am not aware of a test framework as such and i guess it may not exist as it will have to make assumptions about the middleware you want to test, in this case your own.

Comment: I'll fix the jvm URL thing in my question. Thanks.